# selecting the value from drop down- protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a drop down with values - HTML will look like this.

```
<md-option>Hold</md-option>
<md-optgroup>
  <md-options value ='Partial dispose' >Partial</md-options>
  <md-options value = 'full dispose' >Full</md-options>
</md-optgroup>
<md-optgroup>
  <md-options value = 'partial accept'>Partial</md-options>
  <md-options value= 'full accept'>Full</md-options>
</md-optgroup>
```

I am able to select the value Hold, but if i try to select partial dispose, it always select hold.

My Code:

```
element(by.model('ctrl.selectedItem')).sendKeys('Partial dispose');
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks,

the html has been changed. i dont know how to select the values from this one.

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.options" class="md-table-select ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" md-container-class="md-table-select" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" id="select_8" aria-owns="select_container_9" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="&nbsp;Options"><md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_1"><span>&nbsp;Options</span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value><div class="md-select-menu-container md-table-select" aria-hidden="true" id="select_container_9"><md-select-menu><md-content>
                            <md-option class="option md-ink-ripple" ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'')" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2"><div class="md-text">Hold for Decision</div></md-option>
                            <md-option ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'')" tabindex="0" role="option" class="md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_3"><div class="md-text">Deliver</div></md-option>
                            <md-optgroup label="Disposal"><label class="md-container-ignore">Disposal</label>
                                    <md-option ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'Disposal')" tabindex="0" role="option" class="md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_4"><div class="md-text">Partial</div></md-option>
                                    <md-option ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'Disposal')" tabindex="0" role="option" class="md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_5"><div class="md-text">Full</div></md-option>
                                </md-optgroup>
                                <md-optgroup label="Return"><label class="md-container-ignore">Return</label>
                                    <md-option ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'Return')" tabindex="0" role="option" class="md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_6"><div class="md-text">Partial</div></md-option>
                                    <md-option ng-click="$ctrl.onClick(result,'Return')" tabindex="0" role="option" class="md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_7"><div class="md-text">Full</div></md-option>
                                </md-optgroup>
                                </md-content></md-select-menu></div></md-select>
```

Comment: can you past complete html code including by.model('ctrl.selectedItem') tag. As i could not see above model attribute code.

Comment: the html has been changed.